# Is it possible to use Rails-project like a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create two sites on RubyOnRails and would like to simplify this process by copying some basic parts of them in a gem. (authentication, authorization, files management, basic html/css/js design and so on). Is it possible? I mean, create new rails project, install and configure all needed gems and use it like a template for other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has the concept of 'application templates' built in. You can think of them as a kind of initial configuration. Here is a github repo that has a lot of prebuilt templates that you can use as samples or even base your own template off of.

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates

And here is a gem that actually helps to create these templates:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer